# Compler Error while compiling the VBA Code

Tags: vba

```
Sub tem()
Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    sSpecialChars = "\/:*?""<>|"
    For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
        sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), " ")
    Next
    removeSpecial = sInput
End Function

End Sub
```

Comment: Can some one help me where am doing wrong plzzz

Comment: Format your Code properly please. It looks like you are creating a function inside a sub, which won't work

Comment: This is a story, what is your question?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

You can't place a function declaration inside a Sub. Here's the code reformatted, and with the Sub/End Sub lines commented out.

```
'Sub tem()

Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
  Dim sSpecialChars As String
  Dim i As Long
  sSpecialChars = "/:*?""<>|" 
  For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
    sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), " ")
  Next
  removeSpecial = sInput
End Function

'End Sub
```

And when it is run from the immediate window:

```
?removespecial("a/a:a*a?a""a<a>a|a")
a a a a a a a a a
```

Comment: i have done the same as u mentioned above and now am unable to compel it am not getting any option to compel (am using 2016)

Comment: The code to test the function should NOT be placed in the module, but instead, in the Immediate window.

Comment: am very new to VBA and an when am searching how to remove special char in Excel i got the above code from here and am trying to implement the same but not happning